# Using delimiter in java Scanner class to read a comma seperated file

Tags: java, io, java.util.scanner, readline

I am trying to assign values in a file using a comma as a delimiter. The problem arises after the first line, because there is no comma at the end of the first line, so the `Scanner` is reading the last object of the first line and the first object of the second line as one single object. How do I tell the Scanner to only read the line?
The link to the file I am reading is: ftp://webftp.vancouver.ca/OpenData/csv/schools.csv

```
String schoolURL = ("ftp://webftp.vancouver.ca/OpenData/csv/schools.csv");

URL url = new URL(schoolURL);

Scanner sc2 = new Scanner(url.openStream()).useDelimiter(",");

//The file I am trying to read has a header line as the first line, hence the sc2.nextLine() being at the top of the for loop.//

for(int i=0; sc2.hasNextLine(); i++) {

        sc2.nextLine();
        String name, add, website;
        double lat, longi;
        name = sc2.next();
        lat=Double.parseDouble(sc2.next());
        longi=Double.parseDouble(sc2.next());
        add=sc2.next();
        website=sc2.next();
        schools[i] = new School(name, lat, longi, add, website);
 }
```

Comment: `Scanner.nextLine()` and `Scanner.useDelimiter()` don't play well together. Use `Scanner.nextLine()` to get the lines, and then `String.split(",")` on each line.

Answer (score 1):

When it should be an implementation based on [java.util.Scanner](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Scanner.html), you should make it to accept also the end of a line as another delimiter, in addition to comma.

*If* I get the Pattern definition right, the instantiation of Scanner should be:

```
Scanner sc2 = new Scanner( url.openStream() ).useDelimiter( ",|\\R" );
```

The **\R** stands for

> Linebreak matcher: Any Unicode linebreak sequence, is equivalent to
>   \u000D\u000A|[\u000A\u000B\u000C\u000D\u0085\u2028\u2029]

Refer to the documentation for [java.util.regex.Pattern](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) for the details.

Answer (score 0):

### Alternative way is use [BufferedReader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html)

As say *@Yannis Rizos* first read line then split it:

## Java 7

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import static java.lang.Double.parseDouble;

public class App {

    private static final String SOURCE_URL = "ftp://webftp.vancouver.ca/OpenData/csv/schools.csv";

    private static final int SCHOOL    = 0;
    private static final int LATITUDE  = 1;
    private static final int LONGITUDE = 2;
    private static final int ADDRESS   = 3;
    private static final int WEBSITE   = 4;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        boolean isHeader = true;
        List<School> schools = new ArrayList<>();

        try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new URL(SOURCE_URL).openStream()))) {
            for (String line; (line = reader.readLine()) != null; ) {
                if (isHeader) {
                    isHeader = false;
                }
                else {
                    String[] snippets = line.split(",");

                    // Class a School have next constructor signature
                    // public School(String name, double latitude, double longitude, String address, String webSite)

                    schools.add(new School(
                            snippets[SCHOOL],
                            parseDouble(snippets[LATITUDE]),
                            parseDouble(snippets[LONGITUDE]),
                            snippets[ADDRESS],
                            snippets[WEBSITE]
                    ));
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

## Java 8

```
List<School> schools = Files.lines(Paths.get(SOURCE_URL))
                .skip(1)        // skip header
                .map(line -> line.split(","))
                .map(snippets -> new School(
                        snippets[SCHOOL],
                        parseDouble(snippets[LATITUDE]),
                        parseDouble(snippets[LONGITUDE]),
                        snippets[ADDRESS],
                        snippets[WEBSITE]
                ))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

As result you will have collections of 113 schools.

Comment: Thank you! Could you please explain why the  catch(Exception e) {e.printStackTrace() } is necessary? Other than that I think I understand your code, it was very clear and very helpful. I will vote your answer as "answered" once I have enough reputation to do so.

Comment: @user120920 Is a `try-with-resources` statement it specially for `Closeable` classes. Read **[this](http://goo.gl/HBky8)** tutorial for more details. Also will be useful is a Mkyoung **[guide](http://www.mkyong.com/java/try-with-resources-example-in-jdk-7/)**.

Comment: @user120920 You feel lucky to accept my answer ? *Check updates with Java 8 case!*